# Cleaning up a switch statement

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

I have a container class that contains a char array and an enum/integer indicating what the char array should be cast to. I use it in a callback as so:

```
void callback(Foo& foo){
    switch(foo.type()){
        case(1): do( (Bar1*) foo.stuff() );
        case(2): do( (Bar2*) foo.stuff() );
        case(3): do( (Bar3*) foo.stuff() );
        ...
    }
}
```

Is there a way to store a mapping from the integer to the type `(1, Bar1), (2, Bar2)`, etc. so that I can clean this switch statement up since it's getting long? Or otherwise, are there any template metaprogramming idioms that can be used in this case?

Comment: How can a function returning `void` return a pointer?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the cast? Don't you get a compiler error because your `callback()` functions returns nothing/`void`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your objects in a [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) instead of rolling your own using an array of `char`.  Along with [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit), it supports exactly the use-case you need:

```
void callback(std::variant<Foo1, Foo2, Foo3>& foo) {
    std::visit([](auto& f) { doit(f); }, foo);
}
```

If you can't use `std::variant` then a `switch` is likely the simplest solution given a single known set of types.

Comment: Cool, thanks for sharing. What would you do if you weren't able to modify `Foo` itself?

Comment: @frickskit Given a single set of types, a `switch` is probably the best solution if you can't use `std::variant`.